Override Equals method on records
Consider this Minimal Reproducible Example.
Point point1 = new Point(1, 2, 3);
Point point2 = new Point(1, 2, 31);

Console.WriteLine(point1 == point2);  // True
Console.WriteLine(point1.Equals(point2));  // True

record Point(double X, double Y, double Z)
{
    public virtual bool Equals(Point other)
    {
        return other != null && X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
    }
}

Do I override the == method with Equals? It seems I do too (and I don't only override .Equals). Is there a way to only override one of them?

As you can see, the == operator calls the Equals method. You also get a compiler error if you try to specify == yourself, so it looks like there's no way to override one but not the other

To check planes I'd rather make an extension method public static bool IsSameXYPlane(this Point source, params Point[] others) { ... }

With record types, there is no difference between value equality (tested with Equals) and reference equality (tested with ==). To quote the documentation:

The same methods and operators that indicate reference equality or inequality in classes (such as Object.Equals(Object) and ==), indicate value equality or inequality in records.

I.e., by overriding the Equals method, you're also changing the behavior of ==, as expected for records.
A sort of partial workaround would be to add your own method for logical equality and not override Equals. This will allow you to test this logic without changing the behavior of ==, but of course it's a very partial solution - it won't allow you to use this logic in other classes that expect Equals to be overridden (such as sets or dictionaries):
// Not overriding Equals
public virtual bool LogicallyEquals(Point other)
{
    return other != null && X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
}


With record types, there is no difference between value equality (tested with Equals) and reference equality -> I don't think that's technically correct. There is no difference between Equals and ==, but two records can have same "value equality" (same field values as compared with EqualiytComparer<T>.Default) but different "reference equality" (i.e. ReferenceEquals)

@IvanPetrov - records implement IEquatable<T> which is what EqualityComparer<T>.Default will then use and it all ends up leading to the same Equals method.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever  Correct, I might need to clarify a bit - I mean Equals uses EqualityComparer<T>.Default on each field for the specific T of the field.
